# Is It Possible To Generate a ChartJS In C# Web API And Save Image?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, chart.js

I'm trying to generate a ChartJS line chart from my C# Web API backend and save that image on the server.  Is it possible to do this? We know it's possible to launch it on a webpage, post back the base64 of the image, and then save that.  But we'd like to do so without actually showing and launching a browser.

Comment: Why not find a tool that's matched to the job?

Answer (score 0):

Chart.js is a javascript charting library, so you'd need to be able to run the javascript on the server, to produce the chart. This would require something like node or the ability to [run javascript on the IIS server](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=run%20javascript%20in%20iis&atb=v129-7_j&ia=qa).

As you say, there's an option to generate it in the browser, post it back to the server, then do what you need with it there (embed it in a document/pdf?). But that's very much a hack.

As @John commented - you're best off using something like `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting` to produce the chart image on the server, then use that as needs be.